# Is the signature of a non-US branch of a US financial institution accepted by the French tax authorities for French Form 5000 a.k.a. CERFA 5000?

Tags: united-states, taxes, international, france, tax-treaty

I am a US tax resident and I am currently outside the United States. I have to complete [French Form 5000](https://franceintheus.org/IMG/pdf/5000EN-2.pdf) ([mirror 1](https://archive.vn/1qClF),  [mirror 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20200805233357/https://franceintheus.org/IMG/pdf/5000EN-2.pdf)) a.k.a. CERFA 5000, which requires to obtain the signature of a "US financial institution" in box VI:

[image]

I called a few US branches of some of my US financial institutions and they all want me to come physically for a face-to-face appointment, which isn't an option for me as I am currently outside the United States.

Is the signature of a non-US branch of a US financial institution accepted by the French tax authorities for French Form 5000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the public servant I discussed with from the French tax authorities, the signature of a non-US branch of a US financial institution is not accepted by the French tax authorities for French Form 5000 a.k.a. CERFA 5000.